# How to use transient getter in bean for Named Query?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, named-query

I have a tricky situation, i have a property of bean (say getX()).
I want to use X in named query but don't want X to be persisted.

if i put @transient on getX(), my named queries fail..

Answer (score 0):

```
use @NamedNativeQueries instead of named query in your case
```

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the property with `@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)` , instead of making it `transient`. Transient, for JPA purposes, means that the value is not represented at all in the database. In your case, it seems you just don't want to touch it any longer.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the element was getting populated in an XML schema. So i added an annotation to exclude the property (it gets ignored) for the xml schema.